# Get value T from Result<T, T>

Tags: rust

I have a function:

```rust
fn foo<i32>(x: i32) -> Result<i32, i32> {
    ...
}
```

I want to extract the value of the result into a variable, doesn't matter if it's `Ok` or `Err`. I could do that with:

```rust
let val = match foo(10) {
    Ok(i) => i,
    Err(i) => i,
}
```

Wondering if there's a "cleaner" or more "idiomatic" way of doing so, or if this is the best way to do so.

**Note:** Use case is for [binary search](https://github.com/jaymody/rust-algos/blob/5d2cc56d5db2adffc50b66db3788b6585eb5babf/src/search/binary_search.rs#L3-L58), where I have a general function that returns `Ok(i)` with the index if a match is found, else it returns `Err(i)` with the index you'd insert the target to keep the array sorted. However, I don't want to expose this general function, and instead expose two variants `binary_search` and `binary_search_insert_index`. For the first, I just return `i` if `Ok(i)` else `None`. For the second, I just return the `i` no matter what.

Comment: Note that a `.into_ok_or_err()` method was proposed for `Result<T, T>` and even was available on nightly for some time. However, it was ultimately rejected mostly due to lack of utility. See [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82223).

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for digging that up, I knew I'd seen that signature before but couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
fn unwrap_either<T>(result: Result<T, T>) -> T {
    result.unwrap_or_else(|e| e)
}
```

Comment: I see, would you personally say this is more readable or a match statement?

Comment: @JayMody: You should use the function for readability – then it doesn’t really matter how it’s implemented.

Comment: I guess that's up to you, but personally I wouldn't want to keep writing the same match statement over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

I recently discovered this gem:

```rust
let (Ok(my_var)|Err(my_var)) = foo(5);
// Can use `my_var` here.
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in utility method to do exactly this; I would say the match you provide is perfectly acceptable.

If you wind up using this pattern a lot, you could implement your own extension on `Result`:

```
trait ResultUnwrapEitherExt {
    type Value;
    
    fn unwrap_either(self) -> Self::Value;
}

impl<T> ResultUnwrapEitherExt for Result<T, T> {
    type Value = T;
    
    fn unwrap_either(self) -> T {
        match self {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(v) => v,
        }
    }
}
```

Now anywhere you `use` this trait, you can simply do `foo(10).unwrap_either()`.

As a side note, [the discriminant is not checked when compiled with optimizations](https://godbolt.org/z/fcc8vnx3x) (e.g. in release mode) as it's a redundant check.  The payload is stored at the same location for both `Ok` and `Err` variants, so the optimizer will emit code that simply grabs the value at that location, ignoring the discriminant completely.